# Getting deserialized body without binding

Tags: model-binding, nancy

I'm starting with Nancy, and I've run into a frustrating issue.

I have a model that has an ID (amongst other properties).

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

In my module, I defined a PUT method

```
Put["/{id}", true] = async (parameters, token) =>
{
    var model = this.Bind<MyModel>();
    string id = parameters["id"];
    if (model.Id != id)
        return new Response
        {
            ReasonPhrase = $"[error message about IDs not matching]",
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
        };

    await _myModelService.Update(model);
    return Nancy.Response.NoBody;
};
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that at the `this.Bind<MyModel>()` call, Nancy overwrites the ID in the body with the ID in the route, meaning I can't test my "unmatched" scenario.  For example:

```
PUT /orders/someObjectId
{
    "Id" : "aDifferentObjectId"
}
```

binds to a `MyModel` with `Id` as `"someObjectId"`.

I've also tried blacklisting the property:

- `this.Bind<MyModel>(m => m.Id)`
- `this.Bind<MyModel>("id")`
- `this.Bind<MyModel>("Id")`
- `this.Bind<MyModel>("id", "Id")`

However, this results in the bind operation clearing the ID property in the model.

How can I get exactly what's in the body?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I was doing something wrong, and now it's working without the blacklist.  I have no explanation.